# Issue upgrading 21.04 to 22.04 (only shows 21.10 upgrade option)

Tags: apt, upgrade, 21.04, 22.04

I am trying to upgrade my system from 21.04 to 22.04 LTS.

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

However, the system seems to only want to upgrade to 21.10. I tried these steps...

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo reboot
```

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife


= Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 'Impish Indri' =

The Ubuntu team is proud to announce Ubuntu 21.10 'Impish Indri'.

To see what's new in this release, visit:
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImpishIndri/ReleaseNotes

. . .
```

Do I need to upgrade to 21.10 first, or can I upgrade directly to 22.04?

Comment: There is no tested, supported upgrade path directly from 21.04 directly to 22.04. The supported upgrade paths are from 21.10 and from 20.04 (opening August 2022).

Comment: non-LTS releases can only upgrade to the next release; ie. 21.04 to 22.04.  If you're using a LTS release, you have two upgrade options; (1) to the next release ie. no skipping, or (2) upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS release.  You're **not** using a LTS release so have no choice; 21.04 upgrades to 21.10 or the next release.

Comment: You can fresh install 22.04. There is no way to directly upgrade.

Comment: If this is a desktop system, you can *upgrade via re-install* and jump from *hirsute* (21.04) to *jammy* (22.04), as when *hirsute* reached EOL and I didn't need a system for that; I used that install in a QA-test in a install of *jammy* (not-yet released 22.04) and it became my 22.04 support system.  The install method I used had me verify my data remained untouched, my *manually installed* packages (non-standard music player etc) got re-installed automatically etc... but that's an option for desktop systems & not ideal if using many 3rd party packages (QA-testing means no 3rd party are used)

Comment: Whoever marked this post as answered, I’m not sure how I was supposed to tell that I need to reference posts on: 1) using an unsupported release (when other unsupported releases do not have this issue), 2) am trying to skip a release (which many people do without this issue), or 3) that ‘no release is found’ (which is not my issue).

Comment: Thank you to the people who responded despite the incorrect flag. Seems the correct answer is that there is no direct upgrade path, which I did not know was a thing. I will try Soren A’s recommendation and upgrade 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to 21.10 first. You cant skip versions.You can upgrade from LTS to LTS though, 20.04 to 22.04 and so - not that this will help here.

sudo do-release-upgrade -p

Comment: I have the same problem - old VM that I decided to update and its EOL 21.04... I cleaned up my sources.list and tried the do-release-upgrade with and without options and it always says no new release found. Not sure how to force upgrade to 21.10... everything I am reading says to update to 21.10 then go to 22.04 works...  with the repo's being dead now I changed sources.list to old-releases.ubuntu.com..... maybe I should try archive.ubuntu..... ?